# AndroidViewClient UIAutomator Errors On Symbols

Tags: androidviewclient

I am using  AndroidViewClient and its works flawlessly . 
The only issue I am facing is that whenever the screen has symbols like <3 or any smileys , it throws an UIAutomator was killed no error given .

How to solve this error ?

![enter image description here][1]

Comment: can you show the screen? It seems a backend problem tough. Does `dump` work? If not, `dump -F` works?

Comment: No dump doesn't work. I think it's related to se character encoding.  The app screen has stars, and whenever it encounters that I get the error on doing dump or even Culebra.

Comment: dump works perfectly fine running **Hangout** and having the screen with several emoticons. It may be the app you are testing.

Comment: I can't help you if I can't reproduce it, so you should be able to provide more info.

Comment: I can send you all the necessary details, it's a personal project, could I have any of your contact info like email etc?

Comment: Try to reduce the case to the minimum possible case you can share. Perhaps extracting some code from your app to create an example that could be used to reproduce the issue.

Comment: For example the instagram app, few users have symbols in their usernames , or their status has those smileys/symbols, doing a vc.dump() gives the errror.

Comment: Edit:Check Question Again .

Comment: Great. Thanks. Will try to reproduce.

Comment: I  may be a Windows problem dealing with UTF-8. Have you tried on Linux or OSX?

Comment: Ya,tried using it in windows too.

Answer (score 2):

I've tested it on ubuntu and it worked for me. No warnings or any kind of failure.enter image description here

[image]

Please note that I've tested it on the same instagram account and picture. Below is the output of `dump`:

```
android.widget.FrameLayout  
   android.widget.LinearLayout
  android.widget.FrameLayout android:id/content 
     com.instagram.base.activity.tabactivity.IgTabHost android:id/tabhost 
        android.widget.LinearLayout  
           android.widget.FrameLayout android:id/tabcontent 
              android.widget.FrameLayout  
                 android.widget.LinearLayout  
                    android.widget.FrameLayout android:id/content 
                       android.widget.FrameLayout  
                          android.widget.FrameLayout com.instagram.android:id/layout_container_main 
                             android.widget.FrameLayout  
                                android.widget.FrameLayout com.instagram.android:id/layout_listview_parent_container 
                                   android.widget.FrameLayout com.instagram.android:id/sticky_header_list 
                                      android.widget.ListView android:id/list 
                                         android.widget.LinearLayout  
                                            android.widget.LinearLayout com.instagram.android:id/row_feed_profile_header 
                                               android.widget.ImageView com.instagram.android:id/row_feed_photo_profile_imageview 
                                               android.widget.RelativeLayout  
                                                  android.widget.TextView com.instagram.android:id/row_feed_photo_profile_name fercaballero
                                                  android.widget.ImageView com.instagram.android:id/row_feed_photo_location_glyph 
                                                  android.widget.TextView com.instagram.android:id/row_feed_photo_location ? Bloom? The paper kites
                                                  android.widget.ImageView com.instagram.android:id/row_feed_photo_profile_metalabel_glyph 
                                                  android.widget.TextView com.instagram.android:id/row_feed_photo_profile_metalabel 1h
                                            android.widget.FrameLayout com.instagram.android:id/media_group 
                                               android.view.View com.instagram.android:id/row_feed_photo_people_tagging 
                                               android.widget.ViewAnimator com.instagram.android:id/row_feed_photo_imageview 
                                                  android.widget.ImageView  
                                               android.widget.FrameLayout com.instagram.android:id/row_feed_video_indicator 
                                            android.widget.RelativeLayout com.instagram.android:id/row_feed_bullet_container 
                                               android.widget.TextView com.instagram.android:id/row_feed_textview_likes  1,456 likes
                          android.widget.LinearLayout com.instagram.android:id/action_bar 
                             android.widget.ImageView com.instagram.android:id/action_bar_button_back 
                             android.widget.TextView com.instagram.android:id/action_bar_textview_title Photo
           com.instagram.base.activity.tabactivity.IgTabWidget android:id/tabs 
              android.widget.FrameLayout  
                 android.widget.ImageView com.instagram.android:id/tab_icon 
                 android.view.View  
              android.widget.FrameLayout  
                 android.widget.ImageView com.instagram.android:id/tab_icon 
                 android.view.View  
              android.widget.FrameLayout  
                 android.widget.ImageView com.instagram.android:id/tab_icon 
                 android.view.View  
              android.widget.FrameLayout  
                 android.widget.ImageView com.instagram.android:id/tab_icon 
                 android.view.View  
              android.widget.FrameLayout  
                 android.widget.ImageView com.instagram.android:id/tab_icon 
                 android.view.View
```

### EDIT 20-FEB-15

If the problem is in UiAutomator backend there's nothing AndroidViewClient could do to compensate from that.
To isolate the problem, try

```
$ adb shell uiautomator dump
```

in the same situation, several times. Perhaps it's an intermittent problem.
If it works, just try AndroidViewClient after.

Comment: I have been trying to get that working on windows but no success. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Just an update, I've tested it the same scenario on Mac and it works just fine.

Comment: I have been trying to get that working on windows but no success. Any solutions?